# Finding relation between two sets

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-set-theory

Recently I came across the following question, an obvious approach would be to solve it geometrically by using the fact that the second equation is that of an ellipse, however, I was wondering if there was an elegant **algebraic method** for the same:

Two sets A and B as under:
$$A = {(a, b) \in \mathbb{R × R }: |a – 5| < 1 \text{ and } |b – 5| < 1}; \\
B = {(a, b) \in \mathbb{R × R }: 4(a – 6)^2 + 9(b – 5)^2 < 36}$$ Then:
Options:

A) Neither $A \subset B \text{ nor }B \subset A$

B) $B \subset A$

C) $A \subset B$

D) $A \cap B = f \,(\text{an empty set})$

Would appreciate your valuable insights!

Comment: How do you interpret the difference between choices A and D?  If $~(a,b) \in A, ~$ then what is the max value of $~(a-6)^2,~$ and what is the max value of $~(b-5)^2~?$

Comment: choice A simply means that they don't have to be proper subsets, i.e.: they can have elements in common but need to also have uncommon elements, while choice D means they are mutually exclusive sets so they can't have any elements in common.

Comment: Set $A$ is a region and set $B$ is a curve, so it's pretty clear that $A$ is not a subset of $B$.  Or is it possible that $=$ in your $B$ should be $<\,$?

Comment: my bad yes it is <

Comment: @user2661923 could you elaborate a little on why that should be specified in the question, I don't quite seem to grasp the use case of why you are asking for max values of (a-6)^2 and (b-5)^2. apologies in advance for my oversight

Comment: Choices A and D don't need to be distinguished in the question.  I posed that specific question to facilitate your thinking in a helpful direction.  If you actually calculate the max values of $~(a-6)^2~$ and $~(b-5)^2,~$ under the constraints of set $~A,~$ this will lead to an insight that will help you attack the problem.

Comment: Oh alright, I got your point, Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$A = \{(a, b) \in \mathbb{R × R }: |a – 5| < 1 \text{ and } |b – 5| < 1\}\\\implies A=\{(a,b):a,b\in(4,6)\}\\\left(\because |a – 5| < 1\implies -1<a-5<1\implies a \in (4,6)\right)$$

$$B = \{(a, b) \in \mathbb{R × R }: 4(a – 6)^2 + 9(b – 5)^2 < 36\}$$

Clearly, $A$ is an closed squared region. It has four corner points i.e. $(4,4),(4,6),(6,6),(6,4)$

We can check all corner points satisfy the $4(a – 6)^2 + 9(b – 5)^2 < 36$.

Therefore all points of $A$ is inside $B$ set. Hence, $(C)A \subset B$ is correct.